# hbase lzo table scan cause regionserver shutdown

Tags: hadoop, hbase, lzo

i have a problem , some info follow:

nodes : 3 node , but only configurtion  2 regionserver 
os : Centos6.3
Apache Hadoop2.7.1 
Apache Hbase0.98.12

my hadoop and hbase support lzo compression and at the same time support snappy comression successs , i have a hbase table   using lzo compression and have other hbase table useing snappy compression, i insert 50 recoder data into this table , ok ,insert is no problem ,but when i use java api to scan this table , one of regionserver is deaded.

i check hbase log ,but no error or Exception , but i check hadoop log , i found
some Exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF from inputStream
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doReadFully(PacketReceiver.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doRead(PacketReceiver.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.receiveNextPacket(PacketReceiver.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receivePacket(BlockReceiver.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receiveBlock(BlockReceiver.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opWriteBlock(Receiver.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:251)
```

i don't know why throws Exception in only scan hbase table ,  because i execute MR job read lzo file is Normal , thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i finally find the answer , it is unbelievable , Through the Hbase gc log , i see a long full gc suggest , my hbase's heap size is default 1 gb , so it maybe occurred problem ,when i increase it to 4 GB heap , i use lots of compression is normal , so please remember the lession !

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return for the last line of your content. You have to use such condition to control the EOF:

```
while (line = mycontent.readLine()) != null)
{
...
...
}
```

Comment: @QinDongLiang It was an example. You have to control EOF in your code.

Comment: i maybe find a reason , you can my answer ,  until now , i don't know how to explain the reason